# I have setup all my android-studio and project but it's been continously building gradle since almost two hours

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0, ubuntu-17.04

When I cancel gradle it showing following line.

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources,
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar,
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources,
>   :app:compileDebugSources]
>
> **Error:java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied**

Comment: Check folder permission or Internet connection then retry it.

Comment: how to set permission to folder in ubuntu and i have internet connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just go to `/home/suUs12/Android/Sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/` and then right click on `aapt` file , `properties -> permissions` and check `Allow executing file as program`. then close the window.

Hope so this Helps

Answer (score 0):

Use a vpn and try again. I had this problem once and it works for me.